# Trying to mount my Nexus 7 via MTP

Tags: android, tablet, nexus-7, mtp

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and when I plug in my Nexus 7, nothing shows up in Files to allow me transfer files onto the tablet.
When I plug the tablet in I seem to be getting different error messages each time.

```
Unable to mount Nexus 7 Couldn't find matching udev device

Unable to open a folder for Nexus 7 The specified location is not mounted

Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again. Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C005%5D': No such file or directory
```

Tried connecting as PTP instead of MTP and I would get a message on my tablet that says connected as camera but nothing shows up on my computer.

Comment: **This should work.** If you are using **14.04**, is it fully updated? What version of Android/MTP are you using?

Comment: I think it was an issue with the tablet itself since it wouldn't mount on my Windows either. Was on xda and people were having the same issue which was caused by charging with a cord that outputs more than 2amps.